# Ansible: Host localhost is unreachable

Tags: ansible

In my job there is a playbook developed in the following way that is executed by ansible tower.
This is the file that ansible tower executes and calls a playbook

`report.yaml`:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  tasks:

        - name: "Execute"
          include_role:
            name: 'fusion'
```

`main.yaml` from `fusion` role:

```yaml
    - name: "hc fusion"
      include_tasks: "hc_fusion.yaml"
```

`hc_fusion.yaml` from `fusion` role:

```yaml
- name: "FUSION"
  shell: ansible-playbook roles/fusion/tasks/fusion.yaml --extra-vars 'fusion_ip_ha={{item.ip}} fusion_user={{item.username}} fusion_pass={{item.password}} fecha="{{fecha.stdout}}" fusion_ansible_become_user={{item.ansible_become_user}} fusion_ansible_become_pass={{item.ansible_become_pass}}'
```

`fusion.yaml` from `fusion` role:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    ansible_become_user: "{{fusion_ansible_become_user}}"
    ansible_become_pass: "{{fusion_ansible_become_pass}}"
  tasks:

      - name: Validate
        ignore_unreachable: yes
        shell: service had status
        delegate_to: "{{fusion_user}}@{{fusion_ip_ha}}"
        become: True
        become_method: su
```

This is a summary of the entire run.
Previously it worked but throws the following error.

> stdout: PLAY [localhost] \nTASK [Validate] [1;31mfatal: [localhost -> gandalf@10.66.173.14]: UNREACHABLE! => {\"changed\": false, \"msg\": \"Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Warning: Permanently added '10.66.173.14' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.\ngandalf@10.66.173.14: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password), \"skip_reason\": \"Host localhost is unreachable\"

When I execute `ansible-playbook roles/fusion/tasks/fusion.yaml --extra-vars XXXXXXXX` from the command line with user awx it works.
Also I validated the connection from the server where ansible tower is running to where you want to connect with the ssh command and if it allows me to connect without requesting a password with the user awx

Comment: You're connecting to localhost via ssh and you don't have the correct key/password. You problably want the `local` conection type which should be set in your playbook or in you default inventory on awx. But why are you launching ansible playbook in ansible playbook ?!? This looks like a total anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

`fusion.yaml` does not explicitly specify connection plugin, thus default ssh type is being used. For `localhost` this approach usually brings a number of related problems (ssh keys, known_hosts, loopback interfaces etc.). If you need to run tasks on `localhost` you should define connection plugin `local` just like in your `report.yaml` playbook.

Additionally, as Zeitounator mentioned, running one ansible playbook from another with shell model is a really bad practice. Please, avoid this. Ansible has a number of mechanism for code re-use (includes, imports, roles etc.).